# How to send form data along with jQuery DataTables data in server-side processing mode

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am trying to post form data without success and data couldn't be loaded.

How can I pass all form data with array and single textbox, combobox, etc. to `fnServerdata`?

```
table_obj = $('#group-table').dataTable({
   "sAjaxSource": "URL Goes here",
   fnServerData: function(sSource, aoData, fnCallback,oSettings) {
      oSettings.jqXHR = $.ajax( {
         "dataType": 'json',
         "type": "POST",
         "url": sSource+'?'+$.param(aoData),
         "data": $("#frm").serializeArray(),
         "success": fnCallback
      } );
   },
   aaSorting: [[ 1, "desc" ]],
   bProcessing: true,
   bServerSide: true,
   processing : true,
   columnDefs: [{
        'targets': 0,
        'searchable':false,
        'orderable':false,
        'className': 'dt-body-center',
        'render': function (data, type, full, meta){
            return '<label><input type="checkbox" name="user_id[]" value="' + $('<div/>').text(data).html() + '"></label>';
        }
     }],
   rowCallback: function(row, data, dataIndex){
       // If row ID is in list of selected row IDs
       if($.inArray(data[0], rows_selected) !== -1){
          $(row).find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', true);
          $(row).addClass('selected');
       }
   },
   iDisplayLength: '50',
});
```

Comment: did you do web-searches for how to get form data in php and how to send sql requests? if you get errors, you should show them.

Comment: yes. i did it and getting response proper but i am trying with datatable ajax then getting issue

Comment: if you get errors, you should show them. what do you mean with "getting issue"?

Comment: Issue is that... i didn't get form data with data table json data ? both data need to combine..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**SOLUTION 1**

Replace this:

```
$('#group-table').dataTable({
   "sAjaxSource": "URL Goes here",
   fnServerData: function(sSource, aoData, fnCallback,oSettings) {
      oSettings.jqXHR = $.ajax( {
         "dataType": 'json',
         "type": "POST",
         "url": sSource+'?'+$.param(aoData),
         "data": $("#frm").serializeArray(),
         "success": fnCallback
      } );
   },
```

with:

```
$('#group-table').dataTable({
   "ajax": {
      "url": "URL Goes here",
      "type": "POST",
      "data": function(d){
         d.form = $("#frm").serializeArray();
      }
   },
```

Your form data will be in `form` parameter as an array of objects with parameters `name` and `value`, below is JSON representation:

```
"form": [{"name":"param1","value":"val1"},{"name":"param2","value":"val2"}]
```

---

**SOLUTION 2**

If you want to have form data as name/value pairs, see [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3n6a6akt/4/) for an example of alternative solution.

---

**NOTES**

There are checkboxes in your data table. Solution above will not work for form elements in the data table, because DataTable removes non-visible nodes from DOM.

Comment: will it combine data table parameter ?

Comment: @VijayV., yes, with solution #1 using `data` option you create a new parameter `form` that will contain the form data. With solution #2 it combines with DatTables data but in a different way.

Comment: Doesn't play well with MVC.

Answer (score 18):

If you want to format the `POST` data, you can also format the form data using `jquery .each()` function. Let me use the answer above using solution #1 but with `jquery .each()` to format the data.

```
$('table').DataTable({
  "ajax": {
     "url": "URL HERE",
     "type": "POST",
     "data": function(d) {
       var frm_data = $('form').serializeArray();
       $.each(frm_data, function(key, val) {
         d[val.name] = val.value;
       });
     }
  }
});
```

Then you can just access that in PHP like:

```
var $data = $_POST['name'];
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works awesome and easy to understand. There was a typo. Just edited you answer.

Comment: Excellent, except that doesn't work when you have multiple values for some form fields. I had to combine with this: http://jsfiddle.net/XW2Cm/1/ and adapt your code like this: 
    var frm_data = $('form').serializeObject();
    $.extend(d, frm_data);

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
$('#group-table').DataTable( {
          "processing": true,
          "serverSide": true,
          "bDestroy": true,
          "bJQueryUI": true,
          "ajax": {
              "url": "url here",
              "type": "POST",
              "data": {
                   store: $('#store').val(),
                   month: $('#m').val(),
                   year: $('#y').val(),
                   status: $('#status').val(),
                },
          }
    } );
```

then you can access the sample data above through **PHP** using this.

```
$_POST['store']
$_POST['month']
$_POST['year']
$_POST['status]
```

Hope that helps.