# Sending form data to DataTables ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables

I'm using the jQuery plugin "DataTables" to display data from my database.  I have successfully configured it to make an ajax call to a PHP script that returns JSON encoded data.  That all works fine and the table displays correctly.

The problem I'm running into is that I want the user to be able to fill in a form with additional search criteria.  Once the user hits a submit button it would then need reload the DataTables and instead of just making an ajax call to a PHP file it would need to send the form data to the PHP file as well.  That way I can use logic to return the correct JSON response.

So there are 2 issues:

1. How to pass form data in the ajax call
2. How to reload table on `#narrowSearch` click event

Wondering if anyone knows how to do this?

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#table').DataTable( {
        ajax: {
            //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            //need a way to pass #zipRefine and #milesFromZip to index-process.php
            //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            url: 'index-process.php',
            dataSrc: ''
        },
        columns: [
            { data: 'First Name' },
            { data: 'Last Name' },
            { data: 'City' },
            { data: 'Email' }

        ]
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="zipRefine" id="zipRefine"/>
<input type="text" name="milesFromZip" id="milesFromZip"/>
<input type="submit" id="narrowSearch" value="Search By Zip Code"/>

<table id="table" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>City</th>
            <th>Email</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>City</th>
            <th>Email</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

PHP index-process.php:

```
if(isset($_POST['zipRefine']) && isset($_POST['milesFromZip'])){
     $refinedData = array("First Name"=>"","Last Name"=>"","City"=>"","Email"=>"");
     ///query refined set of data
     echo json_encode($refinedData);
}else{
     $defaultData = array("First Name"=>"","Last Name"=>"","City"=>"","Email"=>"");
     ////query default set of data
     echo json_encode($defaultData);
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to send form data along with jQuery DataTables data in server-side processing mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31487738/how-to-send-form-data-along-with-jquery-datatables-data-in-server-side-processin)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this worked for me https://stackoverflow.com/a/38908085/1231402

also to reload table this: `oTable.ajax.reload();` is the working script

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old post, but I was able to pass a formdata to my controller with a jQuery ajax call using datatables.
You need to configure your own ajax call :

```
$('#table').DataTable({
  ajax: function (data, callback, settings) {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'your-url',
      method: 'POST',
      data: new FormData($('form[name="my-form"]')[0]),
      processData: false,   // !important
      contentType: false,   // !important
    })
    .done(function(data) {
      callback(data);
    })
    .fail(function() {

    })
    .always(function() {

    });
  },
  ...
});
```

The `callback(data)` will handle your data but this data needs to be an object named data because you can *not* use the `dataSrc`.

Example :

```
{
  "data": [{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "Tiger Nixon",
  }]
}
```

Hope it can help :)

Answer (score -1):

Use the [ajax.data](https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/custom_vars.html) option to pass additional parameters in the datatables request:

```
var oTable = $('#table').DataTable( {
   'serverSide': true,
    'ajax': {
        url: 'index-process.php',
        "data": function (d) {
            return $.extend({}, d, {
                "zipRefine": $('#zipRefine').val(),
                "milesFromZip": $('#milesFromZip').val()
            });
        }
    },
   'columns': [
        { data: 'First Name' },
        { data: 'Last Name' },
        { data: 'City' },
        { data: 'Email' }

    ]
});
```

The custom parameters can be accessed in the server-side code in the same way as the standard datatable parameter.  Note I have added `'serverSide': true` to the initialisation code to ensure that these paramaters do get sent.

To reload the table, you simply call `draw` in the click event, assuming that `oTable` is in scope:

```
$('#narrowSearch').click(function () {
    oTable.draw();
}
```