# .NET 5 Web Application Throwing Incorrect Content-Type Error when retrieving data for my datatable

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, datatables-1.10

I am trying to use datatables.js in my .NET 5 Web App. When I go to run the app in Visual Studio (IIS) I get a 500 error Incorrect Content-Type. I followed the video found here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NITZdsE5Keg There were no comments on the video. I have tried troubleshooting but I have not been able to figure out what is wrong with my controller and why it is throwing this error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Incorrect Content-Type:
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features.FormFeature.ReadForm()
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.DefaultHttpRequest.get_Form()
> at DatatableSample.Controllers.StudentController.GetStudents() in C:\path\DatatableSample\DatatableSample\Controllers\StudentController.cs:line 30

Here is my Controller:

```
{
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class StudentController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext context;

    public StudentController(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult GetStudents()

    {
   
        try
        {
            var draw = Request.Form["draw"].FirstOrDefault();
            var start = Request.Form["start"].FirstOrDefault();
            var length = Request.Form["length"].FirstOrDefault();
            var sortColumn = Request.Form["columns[" + Request.Form["order[0][column]"].FirstOrDefault() + "][name]"].FirstOrDefault();
            var sortColumnDirection = Request.Form["order[0][dir]"].FirstOrDefault();
            var searchValue = Request.Form["search[value]"].FirstOrDefault();
            int pageSize = length != null ? Convert.ToInt32(length) : 0;
            int skip = start != null ? Convert.ToInt32(start) : 0;
            int recordsTotal = 0;
            var customerData = (from tempstudent in context.Students select tempstudent);
            if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sortColumn) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(sortColumnDirection))
            {
                customerData = customerData.OrderBy(sortColumn + "" + sortColumnDirection);
            }
            if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchValue))
            {
                customerData = customerData.Where(m => m.FirstName.Contains(searchValue) || m.LastName.Contains(searchValue) || m.Email.Contains(searchValue));
            }
            recordsTotal = customerData.Count();
            var data = customerData.Skip(skip).Take(pageSize).ToList();
            var jsonData = new { draw = draw, recordsFiltered = recordsTotal, recordsTotal = recordsTotal, data = data};
            return Ok(jsonData);

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Here is my JS file for the datatable:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#studentDatatable").DataTable({
    "processing": true,
    "severSide": true,
    "filter": true,
    "ajax": {
        "url": "/api/student",
        "type": "POST",
        "datatype": "json"
    },

    "columnDefs": [{
        "targets": [0],
        "visable": false,
        "searchable": false
    }],
    "columns": [
        { "data": "Id", "name": "Id", "autoWidth": true },
        { "data": "FirstName", "name": "First Name", "autoWidth": true },
        { "data": "LastName", "name": "Last Name", "autoWidth": true },
        { "data": "Email", "name": "Email", "autoWidth": true }           
        
    ]

}); });
```

Here is what I have in StartUp.cs to add the database:

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"), b => b.MigrationsAssembly(typeof(ApplicationDbContext).Assembly.FullName)));          
        services.AddControllers();
        services.AddRazorPages();
    }
```

Any help or suggestions is appreciated. I am really at a loss as to what is happening.

Comment: [mcve] is great start when asking SQL questions.

Comment: Try to use F12 developer Network or Fiddler to check the request body, whether the data type is form data or json? Since you want to get the parameters from Form, in the http request, the Content-Type should be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. So, try to set the Ajax's content type as 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'. Besides, here is a [similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31487738/how-to-send-form-data-along-with-jquery-datatables-data-in-server-side-processin/38908085#38908085), you can refer it.

Comment: @ZhiLv I tried changing the ajax content-type before and that didn't work, unfortunately. I did however find a post that explained an easier way to do what I need to do with datatables. https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/using-jquery-datatables-grid-with-asp-net-core-mvc/ and then if you go to the comments he has a link to source files that explain what needs to be done. Thank for trying to help!